# Is there any rational economic reason to purchase XRP early?

Tags: ripple

Deflation is a main economic reason to buy bitcoins earlier. However, is there any rational economic reason to purchase XRP early? As far as I know OpenCoin is not clear on distribution policy. The might be giving away billions of XRP at some point.

Answer (score 2):

1) OpenCoin has been clear on *how many* XRP they are going to distribute, they have been secretive only about *how* they are going to do that. And that's fine, since otherwise people might try to game the system before their distribution starts.

2) You might buy a few XRP if you *need* them, or you can buy a lot of XRP if you want to speculate (i.e. you think their value will rise)